# R Assign Random Variable based upon intere

Tags: r

What is the best way to assign a random variable to an interaction of two variables?  For example, in this code:

```
colors <- ('blue', 'green', 'red')
df <- data.frame(A = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
                  B = c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0))
```

I'd like each combination of A and B to have a random color (e.g., using `samp()`).  But I'm not sure how I would do that short of using nested `for` loops.

```
A    B    RandColor
0    0    'blue'
0    0    'blue'
0    1    'red'
0    1    'red'
1    0    'green'
1    0    'green'
1    1    'red'
1    1    'red'
```

Comment: You consider `A = 1, B = 0` to be the same as `A = 0, B = 1`? Because you only listed three colors, not four.

Comment: No.  And I tried to edit the question to make it more explicit.  I know I listed 3 colors.

Comment: The colors just need to be different for each combination.  In the big version, there will be millions of AB combinations but only 13 colors.

Comment: Something like `colors[as.integer(interaction(df,drop=TRUE)) %% length(colors) +1]`?

Comment: I was thinking of something basically like what @nicola suggested, but I'm getting confused because I don't understand how the color can be different for each combination if there are millions of combinations but only 13 colors. Those two statements seem contradictory to me.

Comment: Nicola -- why don't you submit your reply as an answer?

Comment: @joran I guess that he wants a given combination to have consistently the same color, but different combinations may have the same color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you want, this should work:

```
df$RandColor <- sample(cols, length(levels(interaction(df))), replace=T)[interaction(df)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
colors[as.integer(interaction(df,drop=TRUE)) %% length(colors) +1]
```

In this way each combination will have always the same color (if it appears more than once in `df`), but many combinations will have the same color, if the length of `color` is less than the number of combinations.